# speechSynthesis.speak() works on iPhone but not iPad?

Tags: javascript, ios, text-to-speech

I have a webapp that uses speechSynthesis.speak() that seems to work in Safari, Chrome and Firefox on my Mac. It also works on my iPhone 6 (iOS 11.2.5) but not on my iPad Pro (also iOS 11.2.5). The initial call to speak() is from a user button onclick function.

Yes, I have the iPad volume turned up...

On the iPad I get start and end events that look correct, without any error events. I tried setting the volume, language, and voice in the utterance object to no avail. The API seems to be working, but nothing's coming out.

Does anyone know of iOS settings that affect speechSynthesis.speak()?
Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Doh! It was the @#$& soft-mute on the iPad Pro! I needed to change it in the Control Center as there is no soft-mute hard key on the iPad Pro.

Very hard to debug when every other app works!

Comment: This solved it for us as well. The strange thing is that playing audio files in the browser still worked, but using speech synthesis was muted.